# How do I update a label with an image in tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a dropdown menu with a couple of choices and a label with an image in it.

I would like to change the image according to the choice selected from the dropdown menu,but i cant figure it out.

Example code:

```
from Tkinter import*
import Tkinter as tk

def image():
    list1=['im1.gif','im2.gif']
    studDropDown['menu'].delete(0, "end")
    for string in list1:
        studDropDown['menu'].add_command(label=string,command=lambda value=string:studFiles.set(value))


app=Tk()
app.title("Example")
app.geometry('500x200+200+200')
app.configure(background='black')
app.resizable(0,0)

button1=Button(app,text='Press me',command=image)
button1.pack()


studFiles = StringVar()
studFiles.set('Image')
files =["Please Wait"]
studDropDown = OptionMenu(app, studFiles, *files)
studDropDown.config(font=("Times",16,"italic"))
studDropDown["menu"].config(font=("Times",16,"italic"))
studDropDown.pack()


photo =PhotoImage(file='im.gif')
label = Label(app,image=photo)

label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Maybe even the use of label to display an image is not suitable.

Any ideas ?

Comment: i dont know why,but from every post a couple of words at the begining are missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple example based of the code you provided:

```
from Tkinter import *

def change_image(*args):
    # Change image of label accordingly
    label.config(image=photos[int(studFiles.get())])

app = Tk()
app.title("Example")
app.geometry('500x200+200+200')
app.configure(background='black')
app.resizable(0,0)

studFiles = StringVar()
studFiles.set('Image')
files =['0', '1'] # Number is corresponding list index
studDropDown = OptionMenu(app, studFiles, *files)
studDropDown.config(font=("Times", 16, "italic"))
studDropDown["menu"].config(font=("Times", 16, "italic"))
studDropDown.pack()

studFiles.trace("w", change_image)

# List of photoimages for each image
photos =(PhotoImage(file='im.gif'), PhotoImage(file='im2.gif'))
label = Label(app,image=photos[0])
label.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

You have to make a list/tuple of `PhotoImage`s for every graphic you want. You also have to trace your `StringVar`, so you know when the value of the `OptionMenu` has changed. Then all you have to do is set the image of the label with the `config` method.